# Possible values for state & status of Virtual machines

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, hyper-v

We can get the list of VMs with powershell cmdlets "Get-VM". The returned set have two columns "State" and "Status". I need to know what are the possible state or status may be for a VM.  I have an application that need to perform various action based on the state of VM (specially error state).

Comment: Going out on a limb I would guess that your question was downvoted because it doesn't display any research effort or attempt to resolve the problem yourself. "Please do this task/research for me" type questions are frowned upon here.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers My question doesn't show my effort, but believe me I did. However thanks anyway I got the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use powershell command:

```
Import-Module Hyper-V

[enum]::GetNames([Microsoft.HyperV.Powershell.VMState])
[enum]::GetNames([Microsoft.HyperV.Powershell.VMOperationalStatus])
```

[image]